# ICanHaz.js - Possible to put a while loop in template?

Tags: jquery, templates, zepto, icanhaz.js

Let's say I have a  element, and inside it want to put an indefinite number of

items (based on the user's choices). Is there a way to create an ICanHaz template that allows for some sort of while loop. For instance:

```
    <ul>
     for(i = 0; i < numOfLi; i++)
       <li> {{ stuff }} </li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 13):

icanhaz (moustache) does include a way to loop.

In javascript:

```
var listOfStuff = {stuff: [ 
                      {key: "1", desc: "First"},
                      {key: "2", desc: "Second"}
                  ]};
$("#mySelectBox").append(ich.myTemplate(listOfStuff));
```

In your view:

```
<script id="myTemplate" type="text/html">
  {{#stuff}}
    <option value="{{key}}">{{desc}}</option>
  {{/stuff}}
</script>

<select id="mySelectBox">
</select>
```

The `{{#stuff}}` and `{{/stuff}}` delimit the list. Look at the **Sections** part of [moustache](http://mustache.github.com/mustache.5.html) for details.

Edit: Make sure to check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15650487/icanhaz-mustache-loop-iterate-through-elements-js-error) if you're using jQuery 1.9 or above.

Comment: I'm getting this error when trying out your solution: `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: <option value="1">First</option>
                        <option value="2">Second</option> ` It seems that it have parsed the mustache, but thy is this error raising?

Comment: Look out for `jquery 1.9.1` with above construction. It won't work - take a look at problem/answer described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15650487/icanhaz-mustache-loop-iterate-through-elements-js-error

Comment: Thanks @tkoomzaaskz. I've updated the answer to include your link.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about iCanHaz, but John Resig (creator of JQuery) posted this method on his blog:

See **[JavaScript Micro-Templating](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/)**

A sneak peak...

```
<script type="text/html" id="user_tmpl">
  <% for ( var i = 0; i < users.length; i++ ) { %>
    <li><a href="<%=users[i].url%>"><%=users[i].name%></a></li>
  <% } %>
</script>
```

Answer (score -2):

Nope. Can't be done. You need to render the html dynamically.

Comment: well, this doesn't seem to be true though