# jQuery AJAX response type

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to make a working example of jQuery 1.9.1 AJAX + icanhaz/mustache. This is my template:

```
<script id="user" type="text/html">
    {{#users}}<li>Username: {{ username }}, fullname: {{ fullname }}</li>{{/users}}
</script>
```

and this is my JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("#user-btn").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "../php/client/json.php",
            data: {
                type: "users"
            }
        }).done(function( response ) {
            var element = $('#dialog-message');
            element.html("<ul>");
            element.append(ich.user(response));
            element.append("</ul>");
        });
});
```

The AJAX response from this address looks something like:

```
{"users":[{"username":"jd","fullname":"John Doe"},{"username":"jl","fullname":"John Lennon"}]};
```

With the following code, icanhaz cannot render anything for me. I spent some time with javascript console and found out that the `typeof response` is `string` and I expected `object`. Icanhaz also expects object - that's why it didn't manage to render the correct response.

Am I doing something wrong or am I just a poor newbie who didn't know that jquery.ajax returns string responses always? If so, how should I handle them?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you are getting a `string` returned from your AJAX call, you need to add `dataType: "json"`. This will make jQuery parse the response as JSON, if possible.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("#user-btn").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "../php/client/json.php",
            data: {
                type: "users"
            },
            dataType: "json"
        }).done(function( response ) {
            ...
        });
});
```

Are you sure your `ich.user` method expects an array of users and not just a single user object?

Comment: yep, I'm sure, because I'm iterating through them (see [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15650487/icanhaz-mustache-loop-iterate-through-elements-js-error/15652623)).

Comment: OK... glad it is correct. Just thought I mentioned it, since the function naming looked odd. :)

Answer (score 4):

Try the option `dataType: "json"` for `$.ajax`.

Answer (score 3):

Modify the click function:

```
$("#user-btn").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "../php/client/json.php",
        data: {
            type: "users"
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            // Your code...
        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(textStatus);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: can you explain what is wrong with `done` (you have replaced it with `success` and `error`)?

Comment: It is suggested no longer to use `success` and `error` because they may be removed in the future. `done` is the way to go.

Comment: Nothing wrong with it but this is a much better approach, as I have been using it in most of my jQuery ajax calls! And they work perfectly fine!

Comment: @Marcel - That is not correct... `jqXHR.success` and `jqXHR.error` are being deprecated, but not the methods within the `ajax` call.

Comment: @Will.i.am can you please explain why it is better apporach or give me any link so that I can study this topic?

Comment: Yes, sure. Here's is one [jQuery Ajax Function Example](http://www.jquery4u.com/function-demos/ajax/)! I hope it helps!

Comment: I disagree with the statement that @Will.i.am's solution is the "much better approach".  It is mostly a matter of preference.  I actually use the `success` and `error` approach myself most of the time, but there are certainly situations where the implementation of the `jqXHR` Promise implementation can be of benefit.